# PHP: URL detection (regexp) includes line breaks

Tags: php, regex, function

I want to have a function which gets a text as the input and gives back the text with URLs made to HTML links as the output.

My draft is as follows:

```
function autoLink($text) {
    return preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[\S]+/i', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $text);
}
```

But this doesn't work properly.

For the input text which contains ...

```
http://www.google.de/
```

... I get the following output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/<br">http://www.google.de/<br</a> />
```

Why does it include the line breaks? How could I limit it to the real URL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `<` is not a whitespace character, so [it is matched by `[\S]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php). You can exclude it from your set of accepted characters:

```
preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^\s<]+/i', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine for the given problem. But it would be perfect if other characters like " and > would also be excluded. Do I have to write them into the first [] ?

Comment: @marco92w: Exactly. Everything inside `[^...]` will be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

**How about using [Gruber's URL Regex](http://alanstorm.com/url_regex_explained)?**

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting page. But for my purpose, the regex from above is enough. What are the advantages of your regex?

Comment: @marco92w: The regex is not mine. It's from the same guy who "invented" markdown. Your regex for instance won't autolink `ftp[s]://` or `www.*` (no protocol). Read this and test it: http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand all the advantages.